# Python pandas line plot: change x-axis to be linear

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, axis-labels

I have a pandas dataframe which looks like:

```
df.x = [2, 4, 16, 256]

df.y = [1,2,4,16]
```

I would like to do a line plot with linear x-axis, although the x values are not linear.

Currently if I plot this dataframe as df.plot(), I get this because the x values are not linear:
[image]

But, the above graph does not show the trend correctly. I want this:
[image]

Note that the X-axis ticks and labels are linear, though the values are not.

How can I plot the graph correctly? I tried renaming the xticklabels but it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `set_index`

```
df.set_index('x').y.plot()
```

[image]

Comment: @Dev  Base on the sample data , that should be ok

Comment: I was doing a pivot_table on the original data that was changing the indexes. So first I had to do : df.reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1), and then do a set_index() on the resulting dataframe. I think I am doing something wrong. It shouldn't be this complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Your index (`X` axis) seems to be of `object` (string) dtype) - convert it to numeric dtype before plotting.

Demo:

```
In [99]: df.index.dtype
Out[99]: dtype('O')   # <----- NOTE !
```

plotting original DF:

```
In [100]: df.plot()
Out[100]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0xe74e278>
```

[image]

let's convert index to numeric dtype and plot it again:

```
In [101]: df.set_index(pd.to_numeric(df.index, errors='coerce')).plot()
Out[101]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0xadd94e0>
```

[image]